# Localizing strings with XCode 4.2 (IOS-IPhone dev)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In some of my screens in my program the localized strings work and in some it doesn't.
(Xcode 4.2)

What I've done:

1. Added a Localizable.strings in the folder "Resources"
2. in my .h file, inside the @interface ClassViewController : UIViewController {} I added:

   ```
   IBOutlet UILable *labelName;
   ```
3. Also in the .h file, I added

   ```
   property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel *labelName;
   ```
4. In the .m file, I added :

   ```
   @synthetize labelName;
   ```
5. Still in the .m file, I added inside "-(foid)dealloc" :

   ```
   [labelName release];
   ```
6. In -(void)viewDidLoad I added :

   ```
   self.labelName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KEY"];
   ```
7. Finally, in the xib file (with the Interface manager), I linked the label object with the variable.

So, as I said, this method works in some screen and not in others. Any idea?

**Solution:**

That what a stupid mistake. the line to enter the text should be:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", nil);
```

Comment: to load a localized string use [NSLocalizedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html) or a variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use instead:

```
self.labelName.text = NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", "");
```

From the Documentation:

- **Name**: NSLocalizedString
- **Description**: NSString *NSLocalizedString(NSString *key, NSString *comment)
- **Availability**: iOS (2.0 and later)
- **Abstract**: Returns a localized version of a string.

Comment: Wow, what a stupid mistake... I had the right method in some of the screens. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Vince pointed out, you need to use NSLocalizedString function.  So in this case the code in 6 would be:

```
    self.labelName.text = NSLocalizedString(@"The key for this label",@"Some comment");
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In **XCode-4.2** you can do the following:

1. Click on "target"
2. Then select "Build Phase"
3. Select "Add Build Phase" & choose "Add Copy files".
4. After select "copy files(int item)".( where 'int' may be 1or 2 or 3 etc. depending upon how many items previously have been created).Set "Destination" to "Resources".
5. Now click on '+' & choose your created '.string' file(eg. localization.string).

It works, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you imagine this line does?

```
self.labelName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KEY"];
```

Because it's functionally equivalent to writing this:

```
self.labelName.text = @"KEY";
```

But I suspect that what you meant to write was this instead:

```
self.labelName.text = NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", @"description");
```